# Reading csv file in Python Pandas with backslash and quotes as delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter, backslash

I have a csv file with data which looks like below when seen in a notepad:

```
| Column A | Column B | Column C |    Column D    |
---------------------------------------------------
| "100053  | \"253\"  | \"Apple\"| \"2020-01-01\" |
| "100056  | \"254\"  | \"Apple\"| \"2020-01-01\" |
| "100063  | \"255\"  | \"Choco\"| \"2020-01-01\" |
```

I tried this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", sep='\t', low_memory=False)
```

But the output I'm getting is

```
|    Column A     |  Column B  |    Column C   |  Column D  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 100053\t\253\"  | \"Apple\"  | \"2020-01-01\"|            |
| 100056\t\254\"  | \"Apple\"  | \"2020-01-01\"|            |
| 100063\t\255\"  | \"Choco\"  | \"2020-01-01\"|            |
```

How can I get the output in proper format in the respective columns with all the extra characters removed?
I have tried different variations of delimiter, escapechar.. but no luck. Maybe I'm missing something?

Edit: I figured out how to get rid of the external characters

```
df["ColumnB"]=df["ColumnB"].map(lambda x: str(x)[2:-2])
```

The above gets rid of the leading 2 characters and the trailing 2 characters.

Comment: Is it an option to go back to the data source and request cleaner data?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. Forget about column A, is there a way to extract data between \" from the other columns?

Comment: One non-Python way would be to open Sublime, then press `Ctrl-Shift-F`, and replace `/"` with empty `""` space